# Can someoene please help with customization of a post?

Tags: database

I turned WP posts into web forms, which write user data into the database.

Now,  I want to insert  the username of logged in user into the database - automatically.

I attempted `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();`

However, this doesn't work.

Can someone please look at the code ?

```
<?php
// Preuzmi podatke iz HTML formulara i stavi ih u varijable

$transactionname = $_POST['transactionname'];
$transactionamount = $_POST['transactionamount']; 
$recurrence = $_POST['recurrence']; 
$datedue   = $_POST['datedue'];
$reasonforproposing = $_POST['reasonforproposing'];  
 $current_user = wp_get_current_user();



// Konektuj se na bazu 

$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO prijedlozibudzeta (transactionname,transactionamount,recurrence, datedue, reasonforproposing,user)
VALUES ('$transactionname','$transactionamount', '$recurrence ', '$datedue ','$reasonforproposing','$current_user')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();




?>
```

Comment: What error do you get, or what doesn't work exactly? Have you tried to echo out `$sql` to see if you can run the insert manually?

Comment: One quick thing, which is probably off-track. My browser shows a space at the beginning of the line `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();` and the pretty-printing is different. Now, an extra space like that shouldn't matter, but I wonder if it's really some odd non-printable character.